# Plugin with constants

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

Is it possible to have plugin with properties to access them from another plugin?

E.g. I have a plugin with plugin.properties:

```
some.property=test
```

And I want to access it in another plugin's plugin.xml by **%some.property**

Any suggestions how this could be implemented?

Comment: What problem would this solve?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

You can access resources in another plug-in using the `FileLocator` class but you can't do it statically with references in the plugin.xml.